# Iterating through BTreeMap using range() - question on the type being iterated over

Tags: rust

I am very new to rust and can not figure out the following behavior:

Given this:

```
let mut map = BTreeMap::new();
map.insert(3, vec!["a".to_string()]);
map.insert(5, vec!["b".to_string()]);
map.insert(8, vec!["c".to_string()]);
```

Why does "&v" below have type `Vec<String>`,  (block i.)

```
for (&k, &v) in map.range(4..) {
    println!("{}: {:?}", k, v);
}
```

while "v" below has type `&Vec<String>` (block ii.)

```
for (&k, v) in map.range(4..) {
    println!("{}: {:?}", k, v);
}
```

If v in 'block ii' is `&Vev<String>` , wouldn't that mean v in block i must be `&&Vev<String>` (a reference to a reference?), since I added an & to v in block i. It is odd to me that adding an ampersand to v makes `Vec<String>` an owned value. Block i. will not compile because v is being moved out of shared reference.

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=801d36db2744195527d9360a39a7ee01) (you can toggle between &v and v)

A popular robot told me the following:

> This code does not compile because the range method of BTreeMap
> returns an iterator that yields references to its key-value pairs as
> (key, value) tuples. However, in the for loop, the pattern (&k, &v)
> tries to destructure these tuples into references to the keys and
> values separately.
>
> The issue is that the range method yields references to the key-value
> pairs, not the keys and values themselves. To fix this, you can change
> the pattern to (&k, v) to match a reference to the key and an owned
> value:

I don't quite understand the point regarding the separate destructuring into references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If v in 'block ii' is `&Vec<String>`, wouldn't that mean v in block i must be `&&Vec<String>` (a reference to a reference?)

No, because you don't add a reference to it. What you do here when you call

```rust
for (&k, &v) in map.range(4..)
```

is called [pattern destructuring](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#destructuring). Your call to `map.range(4..)` creates an iterator where each element is of type `(&u8, &Vec<String>)`. There is nothing you can change about it. However, you use a pattern to destruct the tuple and bind the values it contains to variables, `k` and `v` in your case. The first example binds `k` and `v` to the dereferenced values, i.e. `k` has type `u8` and `v` has type `Vec<String>`, because of how you destruct your pattern (using the `&` in `&k` and `&v`). `&v` is not a reference to `v`, it means that `v` is the value *behind* the reference returned by `map.range`. See the [reference pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#reference-patterns) for more information.